# Moving Logic to Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails 4 app I am starting to move my logic to the model (working on the Fat Model principle). However, I'm a little unsure on how best to tackle the basics.

My app displays bookings for the logged in user. In my **BookingsController** I have an action that displays the confirmed bookings:

```
def confirmed
  @bookings = Booking.where(:status => 3, :accommodation_id => current_user.accommodation.id).order('updated_at DESC')
end
```

However, I have tried to move the logic to the controller so that the **BookingsController** now looks like this:

```
def confirmed
  @bookings = Booking.confirmed_bookings
end
```

and the **Booking** model looks like this:

```
def confirmed_bookings
  bookings = where(:status => 3, :accommodation_id => current_user.accommodation.id).order('updated_at DESC')
end
```

I am receiving an **undefined method `confirmed_bookings'** error and not sure what I'm doing wrong. A fix for this and some simple "starter" advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Slicedpan has the answer to your question, but also there's no reason for the local variable `bookings` in your method.

Comment: Ok good to know - so I assume the results are just automatically returned to the controller when the code finishes - no need for an explicit return statement?

Comment: ruby methods always return the value of the last evaluated expression - in this case, an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split your scopes in reusable chunks:

```
scope :confirmed, ->{ where(:status => 3) } 
scope :for_user,  ->(user) { where(:accommodation_id => user.accommodation.id) }


def self.confirmed_bookings_for(user)
  confirmed.for_user(user).order('updated_at DESC')
end
```

Notice, it' would be much better not to refer to the user at all, since it's for an accommodation.

Comment: Yes I should use the controller to extract the accommodation_id from the current user and then pass the accommodation id to the model right?

Comment: I've been meaning to look at scope but haven't had time just yet - this looks very helpful and probably the most efficient way

Comment: or send the accommodation, as you prefer

Comment: just out of interest - some of my other queries use parametized searches (?) - can these be implemented using the scope approach

Answer (score 2):

This should work if you change the confirmed_bookings method to

```
self.confirmed_bookings
  ...
end
```

[EDIT] Missed the part about the current user, that function will be unavailable in the model, one solution is to pass it as a parameter to the confirmed bookings function:

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.confirmed_bookings_for (user)
    where(:status => 3, :accomodation_id => user.accomodation.id).order('updated_at DESC')
  end
  ...
end
```

Then in your controller you can write

```
@bookings = Booking.confirmed_bookings_for current_user
```

Comment: Thanks - it works. Noticed that the Model can't use the current_user value as that's in the ApplicationController file - should I just send the user as a parameter to the method or do you know of a better way?

Comment: Was editing Q when you posted this, passing a parameter is probably the most sensible way, also as gregates noted above, you do not need a local variable in the function body (I removed it in my answer)